# Print div only one time in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to print div only one time. Second it should not print.

```js
$scope.printDiv = function(divName) {
  var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
  var popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'width=300,height=300');
  popupWin.document.open();
  popupWin.document.write('<html><head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" /></head><body onload="window.print()">' + printContents + '</body></html>');
  popupWin.document.close();
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    Do not print
  </div>
  <div id="printable">
    Print this div
  </div>
  <button ng-click="printDiv('printableArea');">Print Div</button>
</div>
```

The total print count is one. Then i want to restrict it to not print. How can I do this in angular js. Can anyone help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add flag when you already clicked

```
var clicked = false;
$scope.printDiv = function(divName) {
if (clicked) return;
clicked = true;
  var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
  var popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'width=300,height=300');
  popupWin.document.open();
  popupWin.document.write('<html><head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" /></head><body onload="window.print()">' + printContents + '</body></html>');
  popupWin.document.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have a variable for the count. You can configure totalCount option dynamically.

```
var count = {
    totalCount: 1,
    currentCount: 0
};
$scope.printDiv = function(divName) {
   if (count.totalCount == count.currentCount) {
       console.log("Already Printed");
       return;
   }
   count.totalCount += 1;
   var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
   var popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'width=300,height=300');
   popupWin.document.open();
   popupWin.document.write('<html><head><link rel="stylesheet" 
    type="text/css" href="style.css" /></head><body 
     onload="window.print()">' + printContents + '</body></html>');
   popupWin.document.close();
}
```